# Can't boot Ubuntu 12.04 64x after installation alongside win7

Tags: 12.04, installation, dual-boot

I have installed Ubuntu 12.04 64bit version alongside Windows 7 64bit from DVD following the instructions on [THIS](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicalInstall) page. The entire installation went as described and there seemed to be no problems with it. 
When I restarted I discovered there was no boot menu. I solved the problem as described on [THIS](https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/dual-boot/linux/ubuntu/) link. 
After rebooting again I got to the boot menu and chose the Ubuntu 12.04 option after which a black screen appeared with text:

```
Initializing variable space.
Starting cmain()..._
```

and after that nothing happens except that the dash blinks. It seems that I can't provoke any kind of response with enter space or any F keys. Here is a detailed report from EasyBCD if it's of any help:

```
There are a total of 2 entries listed in the bootloader.

Default: Windows 7
Timeout: 10 seconds
EasyBCD Boot Device: C:\

Entry #1
Name: Windows 7
BCD ID: {current}
Drive: C:\
Bootloader Path: \Windows\system32\winload.exe

Entry #2
Name: Ubuntu 12.04
BCD ID: {b25a01ae-0cc9-11e3-bbfd-742f68d47a13}
Drive: C:\
Bootloader Path: \NST\AutoNeoGrub0.mbr

Windows Boot Manager
--------------------
identifier              {9dea862c-5cdd-4e70-acc1-f32b344d4795}
device                  partition=\Device\HarddiskVolume1
description             Windows Boot Manager
locale                  hr-HR
inherit                 {7ea2e1ac-2e61-4728-aaa3-896d9d0a9f0e}
default                 {e7a07940-8e20-11e1-a7a0-b36feede8885}
resumeobject            {e7a0793f-8e20-11e1-a7a0-b36feede8885}
displayorder            {e7a07940-8e20-11e1-a7a0-b36feede8885}
                        {b25a01ae-0cc9-11e3-bbfd-742f68d47a13}
toolsdisplayorder       {b2721d73-1db4-4c62-bf78-c548a880142d}
timeout                 10

Windows Boot Loader
-------------------
identifier              {e7a07940-8e20-11e1-a7a0-b36feede8885}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \Windows\system32\winload.exe
description             Windows 7
locale                  hr-HR
inherit                 {6efb52bf-1766-41db-a6b3-0ee5eff72bd7}
recoverysequence        {e7a07941-8e20-11e1-a7a0-b36feede8885}
recoveryenabled         Yes
osdevice                partition=C:
systemroot              \Windows
resumeobject            {e7a0793f-8e20-11e1-a7a0-b36feede8885}
nx                      OptIn

Real-mode Boot Sector
---------------------
identifier              {b25a01ae-0cc9-11e3-bbfd-742f68d47a13}
device                  partition=C:
path                    \NST\AutoNeoGrub0.mbr
description             Ubuntu 12.04
```

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to me you never install GRUB2 to MBR. EasyBCD is just a windows like bootloader. When you choose the ubuntu option in easyBCD it just sends you through to GRUB2, which it seems you didn't install. You need to reinstall GRUB2

Comment: I've used Boot-Repair Disk and the Default Repair options I found on here: [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/114884/how-to-repair-grub2-when-ubuntu-wont-boot/). And now it seems to work just fine. It boots into Ubuntu boot selection and from there all options seem to work. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: no problem. Please close the question and if you want give me a vote :D

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same problem, but with OpenSuse. I had a dualboot and use easybcd. It loads the easybcd first then grub2.

As suggested by other that grub could be missing so I load the windows and checked the boot entry of my linux.

The location of partition was stlet to "auto locate at boot". After I changed it to the correct partition, problem was solved. ..